# bounds on matrix power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, uniform-convergence

Suppose $M$ is a square matrix with spectral radius <1. What can be said about $\|M^k\|$? Specifically, I hope to use $I+M+\cdots+M^k$ to approximate $(I-M)^{-1}$, and I hope to say something about approximation error (in proportional terms).

Edit: I am interested in "what can be said about $\|M^k\|$, and the size of approximation error (by truncating terms after $k$-th power), in terms of the spectral radius and $k$?"

Comment: Du you assume anything about the matrix norm you use?

Comment: Say Euclidean norm. More broadly, I need to compute $(I-M)^{-1}v$ for some vector $v$ and hope to say "using $(I+M+\cdots+M^k)v$ is a good approximation", so any appropriate norm that enables me to say that would be suitable. Also, $M$ is real, not symmetric, and full rank. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Gelfand's theorem states that we have
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \|M^k\|^{1/k} = \rho
$$
where $\rho$ is the spectral radius of $M$.  Equivalently, we can say that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\|M^{k+1}\|}{\|M^k\|} = \rho$.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. But this basically says "approximation error goes to zero as $k\to\infty$". I am hoping to say something about the size of the approximation error as a function of $k$ and the spectral radius.

Answer (score 0):

If the norm in question is submultiplicative, then $\|M^r\|\le\|M\|^r$ for each nonnegative integer $r$ and hence
$$
\left\|\sum_{r=0}^kM^r-(I-M)^{-1}\right\|
=\left\|\sum_{r=k+1}^\infty M^r\right\|
\le\sum_{r=k+1}^\infty\|M\|^r
=\frac{\|M\|^{k+1}}{1-\|M\|}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I was hoping to bound $\|M^k\|$ using the spectral radius; sorry for not stating the question clearly.